# How to configure this external service for kubernetes?

Tags: networking, configuration, kubernetes, external

I have this situation shown in the drawing.

I would like to configure the kubernetes pods so that they can talk to the external docker container "mysql", but I don't know how to configure it, especially regarding the IP address to tell them to connect to.  I can't use "localhost" because that will just redirect back to the calling pod, I can't use 192.168.1.8 because the port is not exposed from there.

What is the DB Host IP in this case?

Thank you for any clues

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                                                          |
|                                          My Macbook Pro Laptop                                           |
|                                                                                                          |
|                                       Today's DHCP IP: 192.168.1.8                                       |
|                                                                         +-------------------------+      |
|                                                                         |                         |      |
|                                                                         |       K8s Cluster       |      |
|                                                                         |                         |      |
|                                                                         |                         |      |
|                                                                         |         K8s Pod         |      |
|                                                                         |    +---------------+    |      |
|                                                                         |    |  Docker       |    |      |
|                                                                         |    |  Container    |    |      |
|                                                                         |    | +-----------+ |    |      |
|                                                                    ???  |    | |           | |    |      |
|                                                                    <-----------+    Foo    | |    |      |
|                                    +-------------+                      |    | |  Program  | |    |      |
|                                    |  Docker     |                      |    | |           | |    |      |
|     +-----------------------+      |  container  | Listening            |    | +-----------+ |    |      |
|     |  Local Hard Disk      |      | +---------+ | Port                 |    +---------------+    |      |
|     | +------------------+  |      | |         | | 3306                 |                         |      |
|     | | /Users/foo/data  <------------- mysql  <------+                 |                         |      |
|     | |                  |  |      | |         | |                      |         K8s Pod         |      |
|     | +------------------+  |      | +---------+ |                      |    +---------------+    |      |
|     +-----------------------+      +-------------+                      |    |  Docker       |    |      |
|                                                                         |    |  Container    |    |      |
|                                                                         |    | +-----------+ |    |      |
|                                                                    ???  |    | |           | |    |      |
|                                                                    <-----------+    Bar    | |    |      |
|                                                                         |    | |  Program  | |    |      |
|                                                                         |    | |           | |    |      |
|                                                                         |    | +-----------+ |    |      |
|                                                                         |    +---------------+    |      |
|                                                                         |                         |      |
|                                                                         |                         |      |
|                                                                         +-------------------------+      |
|                                                                                                          |
|                                                                                                          |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

*Note* Because of the current limitations of the kubernetes system available for MacOS, I cannot persist the data to the local hard disk (to a location of my choosing that I wish to specify) through kubernetes.  I can do it however with Docker, so this is the only configuration I can find to achieve the desired goal of persisting the database files beyond the lifetime of the containers/pods

Answer (score 0):

You can create External IP or External Name service with db host IP and call that service from POD.

Also other options is to deploy db as pod on k8 cluster with headless service.

Just out of curiosity,  why you are deploying db as container using docker if you have k8 cluster?

Comment: I didn't want to clutter up the question with tons of background, but I could not include the mysql container in the k8s cluster because kubernetes for OSX currently has no way to persist the database on the local hard disk.  So I cannot depoy the database as a k8s pod in any way currently.

Comment: My question is: what *is* the DB Host IP in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I do not have OSX to test it, but that statement seems to be not true - that there is no way to persist data on Kubernetes for OSX. To do that you can just create a Persistent Volume which will be a resource in the cluster and then add PersistentVolumeClaim :

> PV is is a resource in the cluster just like a node is a cluster
> resource. PVs are volume plugins like Volumes, but have a lifecycle
> independent of any individual pod that uses the PV.
>
> PVC is a request for storage by a user. It is similar to a pod. Pods
> consume node resources and PVCs consume PV resources. Pods can request
> specific levels of resources (CPU and Memory). Claims can request
> specific size and access modes (e.g., can be mounted once read/write
> or many times read-only).

You can find **explanation** [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/). And how to [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-single-instance-stateful-application/#deploy-mysql) with step by step configuration of mySQL and in this case Wordpress.

About your setup, first try to follow the official documentation about running mySQL inside of the cluster (assuming you are using minikube, but if not there should't be much differences) if you do not succeed we will continue. I already started trying to connect from the inside of the cluster to mysql container outside (my setup is Ubuntu 18.04 with minikube).

Also you are right you won't be able to access it on localhost, because docker is actually using 172.17 (if I remember correctly) so you one of the options would be building new image and put host machine IP with exposed port.

Comment: What I meant was, I can't persist it to a location that I specify.  In other words, I can't say, store the files in this directory of my choosing